# Casperjs withpopup halt sometimes

Tags: windows, phantomjs, casperjs

I have the following code, which most of time halts:

```
casper.then( function() {
    this.withPopup(urll, function() {
        this.click(x("id('lnkInfraT-" + numero_bloco_i + "')"));
        //this.wait(500);
        //this.capture('.\\TEMP\\' + processo_sembarra_i + '-' + numero_bloco_i + '.pdf');
    });
});
```

When I uncomment

```
this.capture('.\\TEMP\\' + processo_sembarra_i + '-' + numero_bloco_i + '.pdf');
```

it works well, but if I also uncomment

```
this.wait(500);
```

it keeps halting.

I'm using casperjs 1.1.1 with phantomjs 2.1.1, when I change to phantomjs 1.9.8 it also works well. I'm on a windows 10 64 bits machine.

When I click

```
this.click(x("id('lnkInfraT-" + numero_bloco_i + "')"));
```

it calls a function in the page which ends with window.close(). Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in casperjs or phantomjs?